# Troubles when trying to install Homebrew

Tags: homebrew

When I try to install Homebrew on my mac, I get this error message:

==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
error: could not lock config file /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/config: Permission denied
fatal: could not set 'core.repositoryformatversion' to '0'
Failed during: git init -q
pc132-196:~ x$

Any ideas of what I need to do?

Comment: Look at the permissions of `/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/config` and all parent directories, adjust if required. And please edit the question with the exact method you used to attempt to install Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the current installation with:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew
```

and install it again without using sudo:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```